# getting 'Task already enqueued' error when trying to add a new task

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

So I'm trying to test out the the task queue functionality in app engine. Essentially my setup in app engine for creating a task is:

```
q = taskqueue.Queue(REQUEST_QUEUE)
....
userQuery = cgi.escape(self.request.get('query'))
timeID = '%f' % time.time()
payload_str = userQuery+timeID
tasks.append(taskqueue.Task(payload = payload_str, method='PULL'))
q.add(tasks)
```

Then a compute engine instance will later grab a task from the queue if it exists. My problem is that when I try to add a new task through this process, even if i deleted existing tasks from the queue i get the error(I'm not naming the tasks manually):

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server has either erred or is incapable of performing the requested operation.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in **call**
>      rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
>    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in **call**
>      rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
>    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
>      return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
>    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in **call**
>      return handler.dispatch()
>    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
>      return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
>    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
>      return method(*args, **kwargs)
>    File "/base/data/home/apps/s~munnypenny-dev/1.374214486618340630/main.py", line 57, in post
>      q.add(tasks)
>    File >"/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/tas>kqueue.py", line 1924, in add
>      return self.add_async(task, transactional).get_result()
>    File >"/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/tas>kqueue.py", line 1872, in add_async
>      rpc)
>    File >"/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/tas>kqueue.py", line 1983, in __AddTasks
>      raise BadTaskStateError('Task has already been enqueued.')
>   BadTaskStateError: Task has already been enqueued.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.5.

Comment: Problem solved, I was just an idiot. Was not clearing my task array after the add lol